# angular-2-dropdown-multiselect is not working inside ngFor

Tags: angular, multi-select

I'm trying to do a simple multi-select inside my formArray but the select don't open with options.

HTML:

```
 <div class="question" *ngFor="let question of questions">
     <ss-multiselect-dropdown *ngIf="question.type=='checkbox'" [options]="question.options" [(ngModel)]="question.answer" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
</div>
```

question options looks like:

```
[{
  id: 1, 
  name: 'option1'
}]
```

The only warning that was shown in console when i clicked on select was:

```
[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking <some> event. 
Consider marking event handler as 'passive' 
to make the page more responsive. See <URL>
```

I installed everything, my module is ok according with this documentation:
https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect

My enviroment:

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 8.11.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

@angular/cdk: 5.2.4
@angular/cli: 1.7.3
@angular/material: 5.2.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.4.9
@angular-devkit/core: 0.4.9
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.34
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.6.2
webpack: 3.11.0
```